# How to Record Audio FIle from jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, web

I am able to record the audio file using java applet but I want to record audio file from jsp page. Is there any way to record the audio file from jsp? Any help or suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP is a server side technology. It doesn't have access to the microphone on the computer the browser is running on.

The closest you could come would be to record the audio using a client side technology such as the Java Applet you are already using or JavaScript with [`getUserMedia`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/), submit the resulting file over HTTP and then process that file with JSP.